# Is this proof of convergence correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Let $k \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $|x|<1$. We need to show that $n^kx^n \to 0$.
To show this, we will use ratio test.
Note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \,
\Biggl\lvert \frac{(n+1)^k x^{n+1}}{n^kx^n} \Biggr\rvert 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \, 
\Biggl\lvert \Bigl( \frac{n+1}{n} \Bigr)^k x \, \Biggr\rvert 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} 
\Biggl\lvert \Bigl( \frac{n+1}{n} \Bigr)^k \, \Biggr\rvert 
\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\, \lvert x \rvert 
= 1 \cdot \lvert x \rvert < 1.
$$
Thus, $n^kx^n \to 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the concluding part of the argument, but what's in your post is certainly the meat and potatoes. By the ratio test,
$$
\sum_n n^kx^n \quad \text{converges}.
$$
For any convergent series $\sum a_n$, $a_n\to 0$. Therefore, $n^kx^n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed are
$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}
\to 0$
as $n \to \infty$
and $\ln(1-y) < -y$
if $0 < y < 1$.

Let
$f(x, n, k)
=n^kx^n$.

We can assume
$0 < x < 1$
since
$|f(x, n, k)|
=f(|x|, n, k)
$
if $-1 < x < 0$.

Let
$g(x, n, k)
=\ln(f(x, n, k))
=k\ln(n)+n\ln(x)
$

Let $x = 1-y$
where $1 > y > 0$.

Then
$\ln(x)
=\ln(1-y)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
g(x, n, k)
&=k\ln(n)+n\ln(1-y)\\
&\lt k\ln(n)-ny \\
&= n( k\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}-y)\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}
\to 0$,
if
$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}
\lt c\dfrac{y}{k}
$
where $0 < c < 1$,
which,
for any fixed $c$,
is true for all
large enough $n$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
g(x, n, k)
&\lt n( k\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}-y)\\
&\lt n( kc\dfrac{y}{k}-y)\\
&=ny(c-1)\\
&\to -\infty
\qquad \text{as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

since $y$ and $c$ are fixed
for fixed $x$ and $k$
and
$y > 0$ and
$0 < c < 1$
so
$f(x, n, k)
\to 0$.